# How to dismiss a splash screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app shows splash screen view which at the app launch while data is being loaded its set as storyboard initial view controller. When its done I want to
a) dismiss a splash screen
b) present the "real initial view controller"

I think its a combination of 3 questions:
 - How to to get the current root controller
 - How to create view to show
 - How to present the view

Here is my attempt which does not work, splash view controller stays. Please clarify what is wrong. Thanks!

I call this method at the end of the data loading method from the "non view controller" code

```
- (void) _showDailyPlan
{
// to get the current root controller
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

// create view to show
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [HCAThemeManager getStoryboard];
    HCASegmentCollectionViewController *dailyPlan = (HCASegmentCollectionViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DailyPlan"];

// present the view
    [window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:dailyPlan animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works. It will work for other view hierarchies as well or for the cases when 2 different views needs to be shown at the app launch. i.e. "FirstLogin" screen, "UserNeedsSignUp" screen etc

Show ViewN Controller at launch var isShowView1 determines what view to show

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...
    NSString *storyboardId = isShowView1 ? @"View1" : @"View2";
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
}
```

Later in the app life in my case the data is loaded and I need to show the "MainView"

```
-(void) dataLoadCompleted {
...

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
}
```